# Will setproctitle ever be stable? Are there alternatives?

Tags: php, apache, cgi

I run PHP in CGI mode (that's a requirement for my application). Because of that, if I run `ps`, by default the processes don't show which php script they are running. They just say "/usr/bin/php".

Since several years ago I've been using, **in production**, [setproctitle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php) to set the process title just like PHP does when running in suPHP.

However, this package appears to be dead and I've never seen it getting a stable version. Plus, it [is incomplete and might lead to memory corruption on Linux](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/cli_process_title).

I'm glad to see that there is a native alternative for CLI mode, [cli_set_process_title](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cli-set-process-title.php), but is there any alternative for PHP running in a web application?